# How to define a function

Tags: functions, differential-equations

How can I define a function which depends on a function of x?
Something like this

```
f[u[x]_,u[x]']= u[x]' + a [x] u[x] +b[x]
```

I think I wasn't enaugh clear.
If I define this function:

```
f[x_]=x^2
```

and I put `x = a + b` I obtain:

```
f[a + b] // Expand
```

> ```
> a^2 + b^2 + 2ab
> ```

Now I want to define something similar for a function:

```
f[u[x]_, x] = D[u[x], x] + a[x]u[x]
```

And for I put this in input

```
 f[z[x]u[x], x]
```

I want to obtain for the output

> ```
> z[x]'u[x]+z[x]u[x]'+a[x]z[x]u[x]
> ```

Is it possible? Or I can only define the differential operator?:

```
diff1 = D[#, x] + a[x]# &
```

Comment: something like `f[u_[x_]] := x`, but defining a function that takes as a second argument the derivative of the first is more involved.

Comment: a more detailed example of what you are trying to do might be helpful

Comment: @ame_math Consider the definition f[g_, x_] := g[x] + g'[x]. On calling f you need to use the function g as a pure function. Expample: f[Cos[#]&,x] (* Cos[x] - Sin[x] *)

Comment: If you define `f` as `f[u_, x_] := D[u[x], x] + a[x] u[x]` and evaluate `f[u[#] z[#] &, x]`, you will get `a[x] u[x] z[x] + z[x] u′[x] + u[x] z′[x]`, which I believe is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
f[u_, x_] := D[u, x] + a[x] u
```

By way of explanation, everything is an expression, and there is nothing particularly special about functions.  You and I know that this definition doesn't have lot of meaning for objects "u" that aren't functions, but Mathematica doesn't need to know that u is a function.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you have defined the functions `u[x]`, `a[x]` and `b[x]` elsewhere, you can define a function as follows:

```
f[x_] := u'[x] + a[x] u[x] + b[x]
```

However, I recommend you read through the documentation on [defining functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

Comment: And if I defined only a[x] and not u[x] and u[x]',
I suppose that u[x] is an rbitrary function, it could be also a product of functions u[x]=z[x]u[x].

Comment: The question is not entirely clear to me yet, either, but perhaps this is what you meant: `f[u_, x_] := D[u, {x, 1}] + a[x] D[u, {x, 0}] + b[x]`

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure of what you want but attempting to be helpful:

```
f[u[x] p_, x] := D[u[x] p, x] + a[x] u[x] p

f[z[x] u[x], x]
```

> ```
> a[x] u[x] z[x] + z[x] Derivative[1][u][x] + u[x] Derivative[1][z][x]
> ```

Which formats as:

$a(x) u(x) z(x)+z(x) u'(x)+u(x) z'(x)$